# How can one add more than one zone to DNS server that use the same IP address?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, bind, domain-name

I have a DNS server with the following zones in `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
zone "david.com" {
    type master;
    file "forward";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "reverse";
};
```

The file forward is as follows:

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA dlcsrv.david.com. root.david.com. (
                2   ;   Serial
                604800  ;   Refresh
                86400   ;   Retry
                2419200 ;   Expire
                604800) ;   Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  david.com.
@   IN  A   192.168.1.37
www IN  A   192.168.1.37
ftp IN  A   192.168.1.37
```

And reverse file:

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA dlcsrv.david.com. root.david.com. (
                2   ;   Serial
                604800  ;   Refresh
                86400   ;   Retry
                2419200 ;   Expire
                604800) ;   Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  david.com.
37  IN  PTR david.com.
```

Currently, this works so that if I type `nslookup david.com` I get the address `192.168.1.37`, and if I type `nslookup 192.168.1.37` I get `name = david.com`.

How can I add another zone, called `david.net`, which should also be mapped to the IP `192.168.1.37`.

It has been a challenging task. I will thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse mappings have *nothing* to do with forward mappings; even though some apps require them to match, both are configured independently of each other.

To set up a forward mapping `david.net --> 192.168.1.37`, copy the entire `david.com` zone:

```
zone "david.com" {
    type master;
    file "forward-david.com.db";
};

zone "david.net" {
    type master;
    file "forward-david.net.db";
};
```

(Actually, since your zonefile doesn't have a `$ORIGIN`, you could probably re-use the same file for both zones...)

To set up a reverse mapping `192.168.1.37 --> david.net`, add a second PTR record for the same `37` label. Note that multiple reverse mappings for the same IP is very uncommon; while `nslookup` should show both results, other tools will just pick one randomly.

```
37  IN  PTR david.com.
37  IN  PTR david.net.
```

(In practice most domains and addresses have entirely different forward and reverse information; e.g. there might be dozens of domains pointing to a single IP address, but that address would merely have a boring `webserver47.hostingcompany.tld` as its reverse.)